# Angular 12 post-upgrade styling issue

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade, angular12

We upgraded angular version from 11 to 12 and the stylings are not applied in production build.

If I run the application in dev build I dont see the styling issues but this occurs only when we do the prod build.

I see in angular 12 `ng build --prod` is deprecated so used new command recommended by Angular `ng build --configuration production`.
Adding the screen shot below:
[Package.json showing the version difference][1]
[Package.json showing the version difference][2]

When I inspect the styles, the custom style we applied in respective component.scss are not applied.

So am I missing some configuration?

Below is the tsconfig.json -

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "target": "es2015",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "watch": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

`
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBq0B.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cy0W.png

Comment: so you mean the css was modified by the build process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be still an open issue with angular that still exists:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9475

you could try doing a possible workaround:

```
ng build --prod -extract-css false
```

Comment: I am facing the issue again when I upgraded to Angular 13. Any possible solutions from you? I tried to use `-extract-css false` but its deprecated.

Comment: @MaheshDharwad try to use `styleUrlss:['style.css']` instead of `styles` in your angular components.

otherwise try adding this in front of your css-classes `:host ::ng-deep .yourCssClass { }`

Comment: @Devis Jahn I use SCSS and in component used style urls `styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']` but no luck