# Angular 13 - How to solve scss/styles issue related with not being able to set "extractCss" to false (eliminated in Angular 13)?

Tags: angular, sass, migration, angular13

I have recently migrated a project to Angular 13 and starting in Angular 12 I had to set "extractCss": false (set it as false) on angular.json configuration file. But in Angular 13, that configuration property is not allowed anymore, it has been removed. So, I am trying to find a way to load the scss/styles without getting them not properly loaded. This has started happening in Angular 13 due to the removal of "extractCs" property. I have done some search in here, found this similar question, but no way to understand a workaround or solution so far. Here it is:
[Angular 12 post-upgrade styling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68015362/angular-12-post-upgrade-styling-issue)

I appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I could workaround this issue by **updating angular.json** file of my project with the **optimization -> styles property** called inlineCritical set as false (**"inlineCritical": false**). e.g. (angular.json):

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": { 
            "styles": {
              "minify": true,
              "inlineCritical": false
            }
          },
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
```